# a partial view works in one view but not in another

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a page that allows the user to select the filters to run a query and then show the results for the given results but keeping the selected filters to allow the user to see them and adjust them and run the query again

The filters are shown in the **index** view and the results in a **results** view.

To implement this I have a controller with two methods **index** and **results**.

Since both views need to show the filters I implemented a partial called **_filters**
and both the index and the results render the filters like this.

```
<%= render 'filters' %>
```

And the filters view puts together a HTML select like this

```
<select id="centro_de_costos" name="centro_de_costos" class="small-12">
<% @cost_centers.each do |cost_center| %>
  <option value="<%= cost_center['name'] %>"><%= cost_center['name'] %></option>
<% end %>
</select>
```

Both the **index** method and the **results** methods of the controller have exactly the same logic to obtain the list of @cost_centers, but what is weird is that this works for the index view but not when i show the results view.

The index is showing a HTML select control with the cost_centers but in the results is a select without any options

I have debugged and I can see the that the cost_centers are both being returned correctly for both the index and the results

What can be causing this and how can I solve it.

Comment: Do you really render partial like this ? I'd guess the erb method likes a hash option like this `<%= render :partial => 'filters' %>`. Do you really have _partial.html.erb placed in root search path of views ? Don't you miss some subdirectory prefix ? Just asking.

Comment: @DavidUnric the partil is called filters so the file is called _filters.html.erb and the filter view is being render but the info of the SELECT is empty for the results

Comment: Hard to guess from the above fragment, but it just looks your *results* controller assigns `@const_centers` improperly contrary to your belief or is possibly overridden by other code (from a helper, hook etc). Try to rename it both in a controller and a view or better, trace a debugging output for this instance variable to see its real content.

Comment: @DavidUnric can you please include your comment as answer since that was exactly the problem